# capture max values in grouped list column

Tags: r, list

I have several lists of the same length and can capture the max value per simulation across all the lists:

```
library(purrr)

POST_SIMS <- 3

set.seed(42)

x <- list(rnorm(POST_SIMS, 0, 1))
y <- list(rnorm(POST_SIMS, 0, 1))
z <- list(rnorm(POST_SIMS, 0, 1))

x;y;z

pmap(list(x,y,z), pmax)
```

I am struggling to apply this process to groups within a list column. I generate a *list column* called `post` that stores 4 simulation values per condition per day.

**I want to save the max value per simulation per day in `post_max`, a list column of 4 values per cell.**

```
library(tidyverse)

POST_SIMS <- 4
CONDITIONS <- 3
DURATION <- 2

df <- 
    tibble(
        day = rep(1:DURATION, each = CONDITIONS),
        condition = rep(LETTERS[1:CONDITIONS], times = DURATION),
    ) |> 
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(post = list(rnorm(POST_SIMS, 0, 1))) 

df |>
    group_by(day) |>
    mutate(post_max = pmap(list(post), pmax)) |> 
    unnest(cols = c(post, post_max))
```

`pmax()` applied to the grouping of 3 post lists is not producing what I expected, a consistent set of 4 max simulation values per day. Instead I am just reproducing *all* the values:

If I `unnest()` and use `max()` I get the results I want: a consistent set of 4 max values per day

```
df |> 
    unnest() |> 
    filter(day == 1) |> 
    mutate(post_max = max(post))  # updated to max()
```

But using `max()` upon the list column cells does not work for a variety of expected reasons: max returns a single value and I want to list of values.

```
df |> 
    group_by(day) |> 
    mutate(post_max = max(post)) # updated to max()
```

Unnesting before computing max values is not a viable solution in the intended application, and I am also trying to better understand how to process data while they remain in list columns.

If I spread the data wider, I can use `pmax()` within `pmap()`...

```
df |> 
    pivot_wider(
            id_cols = c(day), 
            names_from = "condition",
            values_from = 'post'
        ) |> 
    mutate(post_max = pmap(list(A,B,C), pmax)) |> 
    unnest(cols = c(A, B, C, post_max))
```

... but this too is undesirable as it requires manual listing of conditions at "list(A,B,C)" and the intended application needs to be flexible to any number of conditions > 1. Hence performing the pmax operation while data are merely grouped is desirable as this automatically accommodates any number of conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Reduce`.

```
> by(df, ~day, \(x) cbind(day=x[1, 1], setNames(as.data.frame(x$post), x$condition), 
+                         p_max=Reduce(pmax, x$post))) |> do.call(what='rbind')
    day          A          B          C      p_max
1.1   1 -0.0627141 -0.2787888 -2.6564554 -0.0627141
1.2   1  1.3048697 -0.1333213 -2.4404669  1.3048697
1.3   1  2.2866454  0.6359504  1.3201133  2.2866454
1.4   1 -1.3888607 -0.2842529 -0.3066386 -0.2842529
2.1   2 -1.7813084 -0.4304691 -0.6399949 -0.4304691
2.2   2 -0.1719174 -0.2572694  0.4554501  0.4554501
2.3   2  1.2146747 -1.7631631  0.7048373  1.2146747
2.4   2  1.8951935  0.4600974  1.0351035  1.8951935
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), condition = c("A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), post = list(c(-0.608926375407211, 0.50495512329797, 
-1.71700867907334, -0.784459008379496), c(-0.850907594176518, 
-2.41420764994663, 0.0361226068922556, 0.205998600200254), c(-0.361057298548666, 
0.758163235699517, -0.726704827076575, -1.36828104441929), c(0.432818025888717, 
-0.811393176186672, 1.44410126172125, -0.431446202613345), c(0.655647883402207, 
0.321925265203947, -0.783838940880375, 1.57572751979198), c(0.642899305717316, 
0.0897606465996057, 0.276550747291463, 0.679288816055271))), class = c("rowwise_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```